# Python - How to pass quantity in Pinax Stripe subscription?

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments, pinax

I am using the pinax stripe package in my Django project where a user can enroll multiple people for subscriptions.

I know that stripe has a quantity parameter which can be passed for subscriptions but could not find it in pinax package.

Can someone guide me on how can I pass the quantity parameter in the pinax-stripe package?

Answer (score 0):

[Like this](https://github.com/pinax/pinax-stripe/blob/b5b05d207fd9764a604d77c17ae704ded0967a10/pinax/stripe/tests/test_actions.py#L540-L547):

```
Subscription.objects.create(
    customer=self.customer,
    plan=plan,
    quantity=1
)
```